# How to uninstall RPM without dependencies error in cent os?

Tags: linux, openssl, centos7, rpm

I installed the openssl rpm some long days ago. After that i am unable to uninstall the rpm so that i deleted the `/usr/bin/openssl` folder manually.Though I deleted it manually, when i grep using this command `rpm -qa openssl` i can find the rpm.
But when i execute the `openssl` command in terminal it is showing bash: `openssl: command not found...`

When try to uninstall i am getting following error

```
[root@genius ~]# rpm -qa openssl
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64

[root@genius ~]# rpm -e openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
error: Failed dependencies:
    /usr/bin/openssl is needed by (installed) authconfig-6.2.8-30.el7.x86_64
```

And also when i am tryiong to install the rpm it is showing that following output

```
[root@genius openssl]# rpm -ivh openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...    ################################# [100%]
        package openssl-1:1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 is **already installed**
```

Finally,
I need the openssl package should be installed in my centOS 7 or else i need to remove the openssl package completely **without any dependencies** error.

Comment: Do you want `openssl` installed or removed ? I didn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

```
1. Remove using yum, Note: this may remove the dependency such as authconfig
$ yum remove openssl

2. Remove using rpm cmdline, but you have to force remove it. This will not remove the depencies
$ rpm -e openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 --nodeps

3. or try a reinstall if you have CentOS-7 repo
$ yum reinstall openssl
```

If you want `openssl` in your system, I would try (3) first. If that doesn't work, try (2) and then do a `yum install openssl`. (3) and (1) are the options to use. (2) will cause the dependency package to stay in the system and the dependent package may malfunction.